# getElementsByClassName issues with multiple links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The code below is an example - I have multiple links on the page that I want to activate the same function with, but I can only get the first link on the page to activate the function using GetElementsByClass.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {


        var a = document.getElementsByClassName('watchlist')[0];

        a.onclick = function() {

            $.post("watchlistinsert.php?symbol=AAPL&price=25&watchlistgroupid=1");

            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
<a class="watchlist" href="##">linky</a>
<a class="watchlist" href="#">linky1</a>
<a class="watchlist" href="#">linky2</a>
<a class="watchlist" href="#">linky3</a>
</body>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` does exactly what you want.  It sounds like you actually want a loop.

Comment: Yes it works for the first link. My question was if there was a way to make them all work. Where would you put that loop? and how?

Comment: You want them all to link to the same?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I want them all to link to the same in this case, because if I can do this I can easily modify it to my actual code

Comment: either you loop over the collection and add a click event to each OR you use event delegation....

Comment: Sorry yes I am using jQuery :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` gives you an array containing all matching elements. So you should loop through them all, like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('watchlist');
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].onclick = function() {
        $.post("watchlistinsert.php?symbol=AAPL&price=25&watchlistgroupid=1");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also, I assume you're using jQuery because of the `$.post`. If so, you could do it like this:

```
$('.watchlist').click(function(){
  $.post("watchlistinsert.php?symbol=AAPL&price=25&watchlistgroupid=1");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! I have been dancing around this function a hours now .... and it was the jQuery one :)

Comment: Sure, no problem :)